# Show spinner image before loading DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to work this out but not getting anywhere with it. Basically I would like my custom spinner loader image to appear first for few seconds then it fades out and then the Div with id=home should then fadeIn with all its contents.

I have tried several approach but not close to desired result. If there is any useful link that would help please post link.

My HTML page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mytheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/structure-1.3.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="css-loader-icon"><img src="css/images/loader.gif"/></div>
<!-- Page: home -->
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-title="My first app">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-mini="true">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" class="css-hnav" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#home" class="css-hnav" >Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- navbar -->
    <div data-role="content" class="css-listview">
        <ul class="css-ul-list">
            <a href="#blog" data-role="button" data-mini="true">My Blogs</a>
            <a href="#tweets" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Tweet with me</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- page -->
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".css-loader-icon").fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $("#home").fadeIn(1000);        
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.css-loader-icon {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
}

#content {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try with loader icon displaying instead of hiding it in CSS and hiding `#home` div.

<strike>display:none;</strike>

```
#home{ display:none;}
```

Then your js will hide loader gif after 2 secs and show `#home` div. As gif is already hidden you are not able to feel the effect.

Comment: Silly me, I mixed it up :). Thanks for spotting that